# Is there a way to attach some additional information to the link on play market?

Tags: android

What I want to do is to attach some additional information to the URL, leading to the google play and than generate a QR code with that URL. When the app is installed, it should somehow get this additional info. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: no, you cannot pass information from the play store url to the app itself

Comment: I don't know your requirement but I think we can send referrer information in play store url and we can retrieve that information in app after installation.

Comment: But what is the exact way to do this?

Comment: @SteelToe you're wrong there buddy. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Answer (score 0):

After hours of torturous search I have finally found the solution (I think so). Is is called INSTALL_REFERRER.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver